# switching windows with <leader> instead of ctrl

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, macvim, neovim

I recently start using leader key in vim, and `mapped to space`

Earlier I use window switching with `ctrl + {h, j, k, l}`

```
 nnoremap <C-h> <C-w>h
 nnoremap <C-j> <C-w>j
 nnoremap <C-k> <C-w>k
 nnoremap <C-l> <C-w>l
```

And now I was trying something like

```
nnoremap <leader>h <C-w>h
nnoremap <leader>j <C-w>j
nnoremap <leader>k <C-w>k
nnoremap <leader>l <C-w>l
```

I already remove any prior mapping with the above mentioned key. 
 
Now issue I am facing is, with ctrl key i can switch the window panes without lifting finger from `ctrl`
 While with space I have to press `Leader and {h, j, k, l}` simultaneously and then I have to press `leader and {h, j, k, l}` if want to go to some other window pane.

What I am trying to say is, let say my window vertically split b/w two and I wish to go to second window and come back to original.
With `ctrl` key: `ctrl + l + h`
with `leader` key: `space + l, space + h`

I want my leader key work exact same as ctrl, since it is convenient to use
Is this possible?

**Also If you have some advice for newbie like me, I will be glad to hear it.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you call "leader key" is not a special key at all and certainly not a *modifier*, like `Ctrl`, `Shift`, or `Alt` so you can't make it work like one. Unless they involve one of those modifiers, Vim mappings are always sequential: you press the first key, then the second one, etc.

If you absolutely want chord-like mappings, you could try [arpeggio](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2425).